# Unit Test this - Simple method but don't know what's to test!

Tags: unit-testing, rhino-mocks

a very simple method, but don't know what's to test!

I'd like to test this method in Business Logic Layer, and the _dataAccess apparently is from data layer.

```
public DataSet GetLinksByAnalysisId(int analysisId)
{
        DataSet result = new DataSet();
        result = _dataAccess.SelectAnalysisLinksOverviewByAnalysisId(analysisId);
        return result;
}
```

All Im testing really is to test _dataAccess.SelectAnalysisLinksOverviewByAnalysisId() is get called!

here's my test code (using Rhino mock)

```
[TestMethod]
public void Test()
{
   var _dataAccess = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IDataAccess>();

   _dataAccess.Expect(x => x.SelectAnalysisLinksOverviewByAnalysisId(0));

   var analysisBusinessLogic = new AnalysisLinksBusinessLogic(_dataAccess);
   analysisBusinessLogic.GetLinksByAnalysisId(0);

   _dataAccess.VerifyAllExpectations();

}
```

Let me know if you writing the test for this method what would you test against?

Many Thanks!

Comment: You unnecessarily allocate DataSet() there, and immediately replace it with return value from SALOBAnalysisId(). Compiler can't optimize that away since new DataSet() can have side-effects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proposed example test doesn't test the method in question, but rather an overload with the same name.

Another issue is that the expectation set up for the mock **doesn't match** the method called. Again, it's another overload.

The third thing that comes into my mind is that you don't need to perform an **interaction-based test** here. Since the method under test has a return value, you can perform a simple **state-based test**.

Here's one possible alternative:

```
[TestMethod]
public void Test()
{
   var id = 1;
   var expectedResult = new DataSet();

   var dataAccess = MockRepository.GenerateStub<IDataAccess>();

   dataAccess.Stub(x => x.SelectAnalysisLinksOverviewByAnalysisId(1))
       .Return(expectedResult);

   var analysisBusinessLogic = new AnalysisLinksBusinessLogic(dataAccess);
   var result = analysisBusinessLogic.GetLinksByAnalysisId(id);

   Assert.AreEqual(expectedResult, result);

}
```

Comment: thaks so much for the answer, firstly let me correct my original test (there not meant to be any overload, my bad....)

only question I'd like to ask now is - the expectedResult is from the mock. what's the point to Assert.AreEqual(expectedResult, result) ?

or lets day the only thing it's testing really is make sure _dataAccess.SelectAnalysisLinksOverviewByAnalysisId() get called?

Comment: It does test a little more than that, because it also tests that SelectAnalysisLinksOverviewByAnalysisId gets called with the correct value. That may not seem like a lot, but it's about 100% of the method covered.

Comment: small point, but should you not be calling `GenerateStub` rather than `GenerateMock` as you are not verifying any expectations on the object, simply using it to provide data for the test.

Answer (score 0):

actually what you think this little tweak?

```
dataAccess.Expect(x =>
x.SelectAnalysisLinksOverviewByAnalysisId(1)).Return(expectedResult);


 Assert.AreEqual(expectedResult, result);
 dataAccess.VerifyAllExpectations();
```

that way we doing the Assert as well as expect the SelectAnalysisLinksOverviewByAnalysisId() being called

What's your thoughts?

Comment: yeah I think you could do this.  And I think you probably want to, as without it it would be possible to refactor the `analysisBusinessLogic.GetLinksByAnalysisId(id)` call to return a new DataSet (equal to the one created in the test) without calling the expected method and the test would still pass, but the functionality would be broken.